# GitHttpClient get commit of ref / tag

Tags: azure-devops

I want to use the WebApi and the `GitHttpClient` to find some Git tags and identifiy the commits between some pairs of tags.

I managed to get the tags by using `gitClient.GetRefsAsync(gitRepository.Id)`, but I don't know how to get the commit a tag is pointing to.

In other words, I don't know how to get the commit Id from a `GitRef` object.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.teamfoundation.sourcecontrol.webapi.gitref

Answer (score 6):

When calling `GetRefsAsync`, you need to set: `peelTags: true`. Then, commit Id will be returned as `PeeledObjectId` property of `GitRef` object.